# Why we can't assign a variable inside a static block in INTERFACE ? OCA

Tags: java, interface, constants, final, static-block

I have read that constant values defined in an interface are implicitly public, static, and final.If it so then why can't we assign a value of it inside a interface in static blocks. Where in we can do the same thing in classes inside static blocks.

Interface Example:[Throws Error]

```
interface Test{
   int x;
   static{
     x=20;
   }    
}
```

Class Example:[Works Fine]

```
class Test{
  public static final int x;
  static{
     x=20;
  } 
}
```

Please tell me the reason of this behavior? 
If you find this question as duplicate please mark it so I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS Sec 9.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1):

> Every declarator in a field declaration of an interface must have a variable initializer, or a compile-time error occurs.

An initializer is simply required by the spec.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification indeed only allows a *variable initializer*.

This probably was a deliberate design decision. Interfaces were introduced and classes were restricted to single inheritance, as in C++ multiple inheritance created murky waters; resolved now in C++, but not very readable in code, and of
quite limited usefulness.

In a static initializer one could do all sort of things, like `System.out.println` and `for` loops. They probably did want slim interfaces. Certainly not normal initializers `{ }` (= multiple inheritance in a way: order of evaluating a constructor). Maybe someone can tell whether class loading with static initializers in interfaces poses overhead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no initializer for interface. So you can't initialize using `static` or instance block. You can use `abstract` class for these scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

In general Interfaces are used to define which functions a certain class should have by implementing it. So i'm not sure assigning values inside a Interface is the way to go.

```
class Test implements yourInterface {
   @Override
   function myInterfaceFunction() {
     // code goes here
   }
}
```

Maybe you could explain what it is you're trying to achieve and why you need the Interface.

Comment: I am preparing for OCA exam and want to clarify some doubts  for exam purpose only.